# Current Date Subtract 1 day

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to subtract 1 day to the current date. Need solution in XSLT 2.0

I have tried the Current Date() and it is getting reflected in the XSLT.

Regards Zulfikarlos

Answer (score 3):

Use `current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')`

Comment: Then tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it failed.

Comment: What is the purpose of "xs:", cause when i had ran i am getting error, which is as follows.....

[9.1.0.3] Starting transformation ...
FATAL ERROR: XPath syntax error at char 42 on line 40 in {...() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P1...}:
    Undeclared namespace prefix {xs}; SystemID: file:/C:/Users/WELCOME/Desktop/31384_XSLT_Activity.xsl; Line#: 40; Column#: 85
FATAL ERROR: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

Transformation Interrupted!

Comment: The namespace prefix "xs" is conventionally used for all references to XSD-defined types. You need to include `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` in your stylesheet, typically on the xsl:stylesheet element. It's often useful to add `exclude-result-prefixes="xs"` as well.

Comment: After adding the said XSD-defined type, there is the same error. which is as follows.....
[9.1.0.3] Starting transformation ...
FATAL ERROR: XPath syntax error at char 42 on line 40 in {...() - ws:dayTimeDuration('P1...}:
    Undeclared namespace prefix {ws}; SystemID: file:/C:/Users/WELCOME/Desktop/31384_XSLT_Activity.xsl; Line#: 40; Column#: 85
FATAL ERROR: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

Transformation Interrupted!

Comment: @zulfikarlos: Edit your question to show us a minimal but *complete* example that produces the error to help us "help!!!!!!" you.  Know that Michael's answer is correct and that you're likely making a simple mistake in applying it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got an answer, thanks all for the help

"current-date() -7*xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"

xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" (Need to be added in your stylesheet.

7 days is the number of days that i wanted to subtract from current day.

Regards,
Zulfikarlos

Comment: "*7 days is the number of days that i wanted to subtract from current day.*" Well, in your question you say that "*I want to subtract 1 day to the current date.*" -- If you want to subtract 7 days, you should use `current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P7D')`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It's for people like this that we write optimizers.

Comment: Well, for a functional guys like me this is very complex to understand, it is not like an expert in XSLT, i am just copy pasting the codes that you people have designed or developed, hence please excuse my blunder in understanding the XSLT Language.
With regards to current-date() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P7D'), yes 7 days was my requirement but that the code dint work with 1 days as an requirement too.
Please excuse me if i have not understood the XSLT language, i have only stared working in XSLT since yesterday, hence request answers with detail explanation.